# Reset form with default values

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular8

In my angular application, I added default value of Id as `0`. but when user reset the form, it cleared off.

how to reset the form with default values remaining?

here is my form :

```
this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'Id': new FormControl({ value: 0, disabled: true }, [Validators.required])
});
```

I tried like this:

```
dismissEditPop() {
  this.createForm.reset();
  this.createForm.setValue({ //setting back not working!!
    Id: 0
  });
  this.modalBackdrop = false;
  this.editPopup = false;
  this.deletePopup = false;
  this.addRowData = false;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default the `.reset()` method, marks the form as pristine and untouched, and sets it's value to null.

To reset it with another value, pass the wanted formState like this: `this.formGroup.reset({id: 0}`.

Further information is in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset).

Answer (score 11):

With Angular 14, [Typed Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms) have been introduced, alongside with the possibility to [declare a form-control as non-nullable](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#nullability) (Example from Angular docs):

```
const email = new FormControl('angularrox@gmail.com', {nonNullable: true});
email.reset();
console.log(email.value); //angularrox@gmail.com
```

This will cause the control to reset to its initial value, instead of `null`. If you want to specify `{nonNullable: true}` for every control of your `FormGroup` you can avoid the boilerplate code and use a [`NonNullableFormBuilder`](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formbuilder-and-nonnullableformbuilder) by injecting a `NonNullableFormBuilder` instead of a `FormBuilder` into the component containing the form:

```
export class FormComponent{
   constructor(private fb: NonNullableFormBuilder) {}
   const email = fb.group({
       email: '',
       password: '',
   })
}
```

Alternatively, you can call `fb.nonNullable.group({...})`, if `fb` is a normal `FormBuilder`.

Comment: Very useful. No need to use the old way to handle setting initial value to formGroup or formControl